Create TimeLine field with PyQt5
I need to develop a program to enter time reports. What I do is very similar to time graphics.
I was only able to implement scaling, shuffling and pseudo-infinity fields. The main task is to somehow add intermediate lines between years as we scale. And add dates under each line up to minutes.
I tried to implement this by drawing a line only to the edges of the screen. That is, I took the width of the screen and divided it integerly by the distance between the lines and got the number of lines to the edges of the screen. And the distance between the lines depended on the scale. But I couldn't add sublines and make the scaling infinite like in time graphics
Code:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint


class DrawingApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #settings
        self.drawing_widget = self.DrawingWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.drawing_widget)

        self.status_label = QLabel("", self)
        self.status_label.setGeometry(10, 10, 200, 20)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.drawing_widget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.drawing_widget.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.dragging = False
        self.drag_start_position = QPoint()
        self.was_dragged = False

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        '''all mouse events'''
        if obj is self.drawing_widget:
            if event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                self.dragging = True
                self.drag_start_position = event.pos()
                self.was_dragged = False
                return True

            if event.type() == event.MouseMove and self.dragging:
                delta = event.pos() - self.drag_start_position
                if delta.manhattanLength() > 0:
                    self.drawing_widget.update_offset(delta)
                    self.drag_start_position = event.pos()
                    self.was_dragged = True
                return True

            if event.type() == event.MouseButtonRelease and event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                self.dragging = False
                if not self.was_dragged:
                    self.status_label.setText(f"Click at: ({event.pos().x()}, {event.pos().y()})")
                return True

            if event.type() == event.Wheel:
                zoom_scale = 1.1
                if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                    self.drawing_widget.change_scale(zoom_scale, event.pos())
                else:
                    self.drawing_widget.change_scale(1 / zoom_scale, event.pos())
                return True

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    class DrawingWidget(QWidget):
        '''all drawing events'''
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)
            self.offset = QPoint(0, 0)
            self.scale = 1.0

        def update_offset(self, delta):
            self.offset += delta
            self.update()

        def change_scale(self, scale_factor, mouse_pos):
            '''change scale with align to cursors coordinate'''
            new_scale = self.scale * scale_factor
            if new_scale < 0.1:
                new_scale = 0.1
            if new_scale > 100:
                new_scale = 100

            cursor_offset = mouse_pos - self.rect().center()
            self.offset = QPoint(
                int(self.offset.x() * scale_factor - cursor_offset.x() * (scale_factor - 1)),
                #int(self.offset.y() * scale_factor - cursor_offset.y() * (scale_factor - 1))
            )
            self.scale = new_scale
            self.update()

        def paintEvent(self, event):
            painter = QPainter(self)
            offset_x, offset_y = self.offset.x(), self.offset.y()
            widget_width = self.width()
            widget_height = self.height()
            center = self.rect().center()

            scaled_size = 100 * self.scale
            sector_count = round(widget_width / scaled_size)

            offset_x %= scaled_size

            for i in range(sector_count + 2):
                # x_start = round(center.x() + offset_x) - scaled_size * i
                # x_end = round(center.x() + offset_x) + scaled_size * i

                painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 2, Qt.SolidLine))

                x = round(round(center.x() + offset_x) + scaled_size * i)
                painter.drawLine(x, 20, x, widget_height - 20)

                x = round(round(center.x() + offset_x) - scaled_size * i)
                painter.drawLine(x, 20, x, widget_height - 20)


                #sublines
                # if scaled_size > 200: 
                #     subgrid_interval = scaled_size / 4
                #     for j in range(1, 4):
                #         sub_x1 = round(x_start + j * subgrid_interval)
                #         sub_x2 = round(x_end - j * subgrid_interval)

                #         painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.gray, 1, Qt.DashLine))
                #         painter.drawLine(sub_x1, 20, sub_x1, widget_height - 20)
                #         painter.drawLine(sub_x2, 20, sub_x2, widget_height - 20)


                #dates
                # painter.setPen(Qt.black)
                # painter.drawText(x_start - 10, widget_height // 2 + 5, "date")
                # painter.drawText(x_end - 10, widget_height // 2 + 5, "date")
            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = DrawingApp()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Pls help me with this or suggest articles or ready-made solutions that can be adapted to my needs. Maybe someone has already encountered this problem.

Why did you comment out line 83?

This line is needed to calculate the scale relative to the cursor using (y) coordinates, that is, for horizontal lines. So far it does not perform any role in drawing vertical lines. You can uncomment it and use it further.

You can uncomment the #sublines part and there you have intermediate lines.

Yeah I can. but I don’t need 1 or 2 subline levels, I need to make an imitation of their infinity. That is, you can zoom scale in as much as you like.

Once you write up to minutes, then you write as much as you like; you'd have to concretise your requirement and consider whether I really like to zoom in to quectoseconds and beyond. However, if you can do 1 or 2 subline levels, why can't you do 3 and more?

The said site has an example of what I'm trying to achieve. And yes, you are right, I can set conditions for the remaining columns (if Scaled_size > 200: if Scaled_size > 800: if Scaled_size > 2000:) and so on. But the scale in my source grows not in an arithmetic progression, but in a geometric one. That is, for the hour and minute line you will have to use numbers that do not fit in the Scaled_size variable.

How have you found that I will have to use numbers that do not fit in the Scaled_size variable - through practical test, or theoretical consideration?

I thought to achieve the goal using if Scaled_size > 2,500,000,000 (for seconds sublines) but I ended up with a variable of type int (2 147 483 647), that is, it was practically a test and not theoretically. That is, the way to add another condition for the line does not work. Now I’ll try to change the algorithm to increase the scale in arithmetic progression.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Code725 –
You should have posted the test code which exhibited the problem and stated the problem at the outset. - Previously you wrote hour and minute line, now you talk about seconds; I must repeat you'd have to concretise your requirement.

I don’t have any requirements regarding seconds and minutes. I need to create an algorithm for drawing sublines similar to those in Desmos, TimeLine editor, or Google Maps. These interfaces allow dragging the field with the left mouse button and changing the scale with the mouse wheel. I’ve solved the issue of a pseudo-infinite field but need help with the scale drawing algorithm.

Specifically, I want to draw sublines indefinitely, like in the mentioned editors, but I’m struggling to achieve this. The goal is to have continuous subline drawing, not limited to minutes or seconds. I mentioned them to make it clear what this is for and for what scale it is needed.

Example
https://www.boristhebrave.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/quadtree2_zoom.gif
distant lines disappear,
it’s also possible vice versa so that they appear

and no, I didn’t go off topic. if you remove the horizontal lines then this will be what I need


add dates under each line

A date can be added to each line depending on the widget's offset, e. g. for years:
    toyear = 2024+(offset_x-self.offset.x())/scaled_size
    painter.drawText(x_start - 10, widget_height // 2 + 5, "%d"%(toyear-i))
    painter.drawText(x_end - 10, widget_height // 2 + 5, "%d"%(toyear+i))

This can of course be expanded for sublines as desired.
Note that you must not limit scale to 100 if you want to zoom in beyond days.
